# c#, 2 date pickers, 1 text box

Tags: c#

what would like code look like if I have 2 date pickers on the form for the customer to chose a rental start date and a rental return date, calculate the difference between the 2 dates and put that into the text box.

I want the customer to be able to pick a rental start and end dates.  Have the calculation then enter the # of days into the text box,  then use the number entered in the text box in another calculation.

I have dtpStartDate, dtpReturnDate & txtDays
This would be part of the code under my btnCalc_Click event handler.
Do I need to declare StartDate & ReturnDate as variables first?
I have a variable days that I am already using in another calculation.

```
      /* This method calculates vehicle cost, add ons, discount and rental total cost
     */
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        decimal addItemsCost = 0.0m;                //Cost of the selected additional items
        decimal rentalTotal;                        //Total cost of the rental
        int days;                                   //Number of rental days
        decimal discountTotal = 0.0m;               //Total discount if promotion criteria met

        //Transfer inputs to variables
        days = int.Parse(vTools.unformat(txtDays.Text));

        //Vehicle cost determined by rdoVehicle Check Changed

        //Calculate additional item cost
        if (chkDvd.Checked)         addItemsCost += DVDCOST;
        if (chkAir.Checked)         addItemsCost += AIRCOST;
        if (chkCarSeat.Checked)     addItemsCost += CARSEATCOST;
        if (chkInsurance.Checked)   addItemsCost += INSURANCECOST;


        //Calculate the total cost of add on's and total rental cost
        if (days >= PROMODAYS && rdoLuxury.Checked) {
          rentalTotal = ((vehicleCost * days) + addItemsCost - discountTotal );
          discountTotal = rentalTotal * PDISCOUNT;

        } else {
            rentalTotal = (vehicleCost * days) + addItemsCost;
        }//end if else
          rentalTotal = (vehicleCost * days) + addItemsCost - discountTotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the two dates from the text boxes to `DateTime` objects `EndDate` and `StartDate`, and then calculate the interval:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Parse(myStartDateTextBox.Text);

var endDate  = DateTime.Parse(myEndDateTextBox.Text);

myIntervalTextBox.Text = (endDate - startDate).TotalDays.ToString();
```

Comment: When you say from the text boxes, is that the same as the date pickers?

Comment: Wherever you are allowing your users to put in the dates.  If the date pickers are already handing you `DateTime` objects, so much the better.

Comment: Ok that works,  now how do I take the txtDays text box and use that number in other calculations?

Comment: Assign  `(endDate - startDate).TotalDays` to your `days` variable.